# JSF and Maven simple example. Unable to print managed bean message to the xhtml

Tags: java, jsf

I am new in JSF and I am trying to do a basic exercise: Print a ManagedBean message on xhtml file.
I've searched some information that can help me but no luck.

This is how my files look like:

**EngineController.java (where my managed bean is)**

```
    package java;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    @ManagedBean(name = "engineController")
    @SessionScoped
    public class EngineController implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{msgTurnOnBtn}")
    private String msgTurnOnBtn = "Encender";

    public String getMsgTurnOnBtn() {
        System.out.println(msgTurnOnBtn);
        return msgTurnOnBtn;
    }

    public void setMsgTurnOnBtn(String msgTurnOnBtn) {
        this.msgTurnOnBtn = msgTurnOnBtn;
    }
}
```

**home.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>Primera Practica</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h2>Motor</h2>
            <h:outputText value="#{engineController.msgTurnOnBtn}" />
            <h:commandButton id="turnOnBtn" 
                             value="#{engineController.msgTurnOnBtn}"
                             >
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Practica1</display-name>

    <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Practica1</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Practica1 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat 6 need this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Practica1</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

So the problem is that I can't see the message within #{engineController.msgTurnOnBtn} on my home.xhtml file.

*By the way, one of my colleague has implemented another code that looks the same way and I am able to execute with no problems.*

Thanks in advance, guys :)

Comment: What *do* you see in your browser? Just a white page? If so, when you do a "view source",  what do you see there? Do you see html or do you see the literal xhtml code from home.xhtml?

Comment: here is a good tutorial, worked for me: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/

Comment: btw: you don't need  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{msgTurnOnBtn}") on your String property...

Comment: @Gimby What I see is just the Title (h2) 'Motor' and under it the commandButton without text (my message from Managed Bean). Image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vb0wga99sy2s1sa/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202015-10-29%2010.17.56.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- change the name of your package to something other than "java"
- don't put @ManagedProperty(value = "#{msgTurnOnBtn}") on your String property

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. The reason was that @ManagedProperty(value = "#{msgTurnOnBtn}"). With it doesn't work and without it it works. I don't really know why but this is it. I guess is something related with the java version (mine is 1.8.0_25).

Comment: @FLBKernel you could take a moment and read what the purpose is of ManagedProperty. Just a thought, but usually when you guess you guess wrong. Especially when your first guess is to blame the tools.

Comment: @FBLKernel : with package-name "java", i get an java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.EngineController, not sure why this works for you

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I changed the name to a different one but I was still getting the same problem so I think the problem was ManagedProperty and not the name of the package. I keep wondering why. I thought ManagedProperty is necessary to access to the property and get its value.

Comment: @FBLKernel: but "String" is not "managed" by a container. You need ManagedProperty if you want to inject other managed beans (such as JSF or Spring beans) into your JSF managed Bean

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Alright, now I understand. Thank you again :)